# Integrating internal office applications with Google Workspace OpenID SSO

Tags: google-workspace

We have internal office apps like redmine, jenkins etc. that we want to access after signing into Google Workspace using OpenID SSO configured within Google Cloud Console.

To try achieving this, we are trying to add redmine, jenkins etc. apps by visiting admin.google.com -> Apps -> Web and mobile apps -> Add app menu button.  However, we don't see OpenID support, we see only "Add custom SAML app" option.

Would request help in knowing below things:

1. Isn't OpenID connect supported yet?
2. Does our internal application i.e., redmine, jenkins etc. configured using "Add custom SAML app" option mentioned above appear as another application in addition to default applications like calendar, gmail, meet etc. displayed by Google Workspace?
3. Can we access these internal apps within the waffle (grid icon) area at the top right corner at google workspace dashboard similar to accessing calendar, gmail etc. from waffle area?

The main objective is to display our internal apps redmine, jenkins etc. as additional applications below the standard default apps that are displayed by google workspace after we sign in.  That way, we can just click on redmine and get to the dashboard rather than signing in again using redmine specific user id and password.